# rdd.collect().map in spark, taking time to compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am working on a task where I using multiple dataframes and apply joins with another dataframes.

The combined result is mapped and I am using `pNodeArray.rdd.collect().map(f=>{`

`pNodeArray` is dataframe which I created from another dataframe using

```
df.groupBy("P_XX_M", "G_RM_XX_D", "B_CD_XD")
.agg(collect_list(struct("col1","col2"......)

var pmap = pNodeArray.rdd.collect().map(f=>{
var P_ISD = if (f.getAs[Any]("P_ISD") != null) f.getAs("P_ISD").toString() else null
}).toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

is there any easy way to solve this or different approach or suggestion to reduce time
for eg: for the task i am working only one one ID the underlying db has millions or records.
For one ID it is taking 35 min to complete and the collect().map  is taking more time

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can, eliminate the `collect()` or at least try to limit the amount of data being sent back to the driver to definitely increase processing speed. Can you give us some test data and your desired output for us to mess around with?

Comment: collect()  fetch data from all the nodes to the driver node. so it always needs to identify the requirement of output and use it wisely.

Comment: In order to know if all executors are being used or not for a stage, it is better to check how many executors are running the tasks in the Executors tab in Spark History Server.

Comment: i gave configs like this,--executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 32g --num-executors 20 --executor-cores 5 , 4 active tasks are running